# Array is returning all values instead of 1 (Schoolwork)

Tags: c#

In short i'm trying to make a list in which the user edits one of the values in the array and not all of them, the problem is that the last foreach replaces all values in the array with the input of the user and not with the index that the user requested :/

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] array = new string [5] { "Duhh", "Bla", "Lel", "Meow", "Lelz" };
        string exit = "Q";

        foreach (string value in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Värdena är " +value);
        }

            Console.WriteLine("Skriv in vilket värde du vill ändra (nummerordning)");
            int index = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            index = index - 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ditt nya namn");
            string newname = Console.ReadLine();
            array[index] = newname;
        foreach (string value in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dina nya namn är " +newname);
        }


            Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Dina nya namn är " +newname);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is your typo.

```
foreach (string value in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dina nya namn är " +value);
        }
```

Comment: What type should i use to write the output? I'm confused why it replaces all of them :S

Comment: You have to use variable you have used in foreach. You are using newname which you read from console. Even though you loop through it but you print newname so it is issue.

Comment: @MertDemirsü it does not replace all of the items in the array, you are simply writing out the value the user enters for each item in the array, rather than the item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
Console.WriteLine("Dina nya namn är " +newname);
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine("Dina nya namn är " + value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a bad variable in your last loop:
You should write:

```
foreach (string value in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dina nya namn är " + value);
}
```

instead of:

```
foreach (string value in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dina nya namn är " + newname);
}
```

Comment: `newname`is not a bad variable. `newname` is rather nice. It's just not the correct one.